# How to remove shadow on scroll RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a `RecyclerView` with different list items. I don't know why but there is a shadow dropped by list items. This shadow appears when I scroll up and down. I want to get rid of this shadow, but found nothing that could help me. Any suggestions? Here's my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.lanet_contactwork.activities.LoginActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

--------------------------------------**Update: added item layouts-**---------------------------

**FIRST ITEM LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/divider_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**SECOND ITEM LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/task"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/task_type_img"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_sort_grey" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/address_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_type_img" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10:00"
        android:id="@+id/time_txt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/address_details_txt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_type_img" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of it ?

Comment: I think he is referring to the bounce shadow that happens when you try to scroll past the edge...

Comment: @cgr I don't know how to make screenshot while scrolling on a Genymotion device.

Comment: @Shmuel No, that shadow is ok. I mean shadow which is dropped by one item on another while you scroll.

Comment: @RexSpole, can you copy your adapter item(s) layout ?

Comment: @cgr Edited the post, added layouts. The second item drops shadow on first. In a list they are situated one after another.

Comment: can you once check it on some device?

Comment: @Amit Tiwari Thanks:) I checked on a device and there was no shadow. It is probably some emulator bug or I don't know.

Comment: @RexSplode good to know. Always try to keep a device for USB debugging . It would be far more useful than any emulator.

Answer (score 69):

Add this to your `RecyclerView`:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
   `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>`
```

`android:overScrollMode="never"`

This helped me to remove shadow at the start of the recyclerView and at the end as well

Answer (score -2):

add this code to your RecyclerViewor other scrollable view:

`android:overScrollMode="never"`